# PDF to HTML library in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, text

I want to convert my pdf file which contains texts only to an html format.
I want to retrieve the contents (texts, formats,indentions, etc..) and store it in variable for display with the same formatting, arrangement, indentions.

Can anyone suggest a PHP class/library (not a software tool, no installation needed) that I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

pdf2text gives you exactly what it says: it extracts the **text** from a pdf file, it does not convert it to **html markup**. You'll probably need to use a command line utility, or an online service for this.

There's the linux command line [pdftohtml](http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/) tool

[Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) is another option, it contains a utility called pdftohtml

or there's [jPedal](http://www.jpedal.org/html_index.php) if you're prepred to consider a java app

There's also a whole range of commercial apps that will do this, but I'm guessing you want "free"

Comment: I haven't used them, I'm just aware of their existence.... so I can't really comment on how good they are, or how to use them

Answer (score 0):

You can use FPDI - PDF-Parser (COMERCIAL) to import text form your pdf files, or FPDI (FREE) to import like pdf templates (you connot modify text on free version). Or you can store some html formated templates and shortcodes and create new pdf's using TCPDF: Open Source PHP Class.

Comment: I guess the FPDI is more in generating PDF's and not reading it. What I want is to read the contents(texts) of a pdf file and store it in a php variable and display with the same format(bolds,italics,indentions,etc..) with the pdf